# Please help me understand the following transition in the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I was trying to figure out how a limit was calculated and got stuck when trying to understand one of the proposed solutions: (note that this is just a small part of the solution, but the one that got me in trouble)

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\sqrt{k}\right|   
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}+\sqrt{2k}} $$

In my opinion, whether $n$ is odd or even has an impact on the sum. Plugging a few random $n$-s doesn't help to prove the validity of the formula for me.

I guess this is one of the cases when I am puzzled and can't see something obvious. If someone could clarify it for me, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Prove that the effect of $n$ odd/even disappears in the limit.

Comment: I mean that without considering the limit, the transition from one sum to the other is not correct for some finite $n$, right?

Comment: When $ n = 2m $, we get: $$ \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{m}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}}}$$

And for odd $n$: $$ \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m+1}} |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{m}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}-\sqrt{2m+1}|}}$$

Comment: Honestly, it's not obvious to me that the effect of $n$ being odd/even disappears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:*

In order to show the validity of the claim it follows from your comment 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{m\to \infty}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}\\
\lim_{m\to \infty}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m+1}}\left|\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}-\sqrt{2m+1}\right|\\
&=\lim_{m\to \infty}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}-1\right|\\
\end{align*}
that

> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} (-1)^k\sqrt{k}
> &=\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}\\
> &=\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m+1}}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}
> \end{align*}